# How can I "Delete All" but only when a column has a certain value?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to `MERGE` a set of records into a table. The `UpdateType` column in the source determines if I should `DELETE` rows in the target that are not in the source.

So `UpdateType` will equal `D` or `R`... D=Delta, R=Refresh

If `D`, do NOT `DELETE` non matching from target
If `R`, DO `DELETE` non matching from target.

I have a `WHILE` that iterates over a single table, to just better mimic how the process works.

Can I accomplish this in a MERGE? Or what other options do I have?

**SQL Fiddle:** http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cdfe/16

Here is my example, the only problem is... I can't use a source value in the `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE` clause.

```
DECLARE @BaseTable TABLE
(   RN int  
    ,Store int
    ,UpdateType char(1)
    ,ItemNumber int
    ,Name varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @BaseTable
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 RN, 1 Store, 'D' UpdateType, 1 ItemNumber, 'Wheel' Name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 1, 'D', 1, 'Big Wheel'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 1, 'D', 2, 'Light'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1, 'R', 1, 'Wide Wheel'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 1, 'D', 1, 'Small Wheel'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 1, 'D', 4, 'Trunk'
)B

SELECT bt.* FROM @BaseTable bt

DECLARE @Tab TABLE
(   Store int
    ,UpdateType char(1)
    ,ItemNumber int
    ,Name varchar(50)
)

DECLARE @count int = 1
--Loop over each row to mimic how the merge will be called.
WHILE @count <= 5
BEGIN  
    MERGE INTO @Tab T
    USING
    (
        SELECT bt.RN,
                bt.Store,
                bt.UpdateType,
                bt.ItemNumber,
                bt.Name,
                tab.Store IsRefresh
        FROM @BaseTable bt
        LEFT JOIN
        (   --If ANY previous ITERATION was a 'R' then, all subsequent UpdateType MUST = 'R'
            --I'm hoping there is a better way to accomplish this.
            SELECT Store
            FROM @Tab
            WHERE UpdateType = 'R'
            GROUP BY Store
            HAVING COUNT(Store) > 1
        )tab
            ON bt.Store = tab.Store
        WHERE bt.RN = @count
    )S
        ON S.Store = T.Store AND S.ItemNumber = T.ItemNumber
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
        UPDATE
        SET T.UpdateType = CASE WHEN S.IsRefresh IS NOT NULL THEN 'R' ELSE S.UpdateType END,
        T.Name = S.Name
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
        INSERT(Store,UpdateType,ItemNumber,Name) VALUES(S.Store,S.UpdateType,S.ItemNumber,S.Name)
    --WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND S.UpdateType = 'R' THEN
    --  DELETE
        ;
    SET @count = @count + 1
END

SELECT * FROM @Tab

--@Tab Expected Result:
-- 1 'R' 1 'Small Wheel'
-- 1 'R' 4 'Trunk'
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't completely understand your output. Why is there no `ItemNumber = 2` there?

Comment: Because when it iterates to `RN=4`, the `UpdateType='R'`, which would "delete all in `@tab` that do not match". Since `RN=4`, does not have a record for 'ItemNumber=2', that will get deleted and only `ItemNumber=1` will be updated. `RN=5` will update `ItemNumber=1` and insert `ItemNumber=4`. Does that help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code appears to do what you want:

```
CREATE TABLE #BaseTable
(   RN int  
    ,Store int
    ,UpdateType char(1)
    ,ItemNumber int
    ,Name varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #BaseTable
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 RN, 1 Store, 'D' UpdateType, 1 ItemNumber, 'Wheel' Name
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 1, 'D', 1, 'Big Wheel'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3, 1, 'D', 2, 'Light'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4, 1, 'R', 1, 'Wide Wheel'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 1, 'D', 1, 'Small Wheel'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5, 1, 'D', 4, 'Trunk'
)B

CREATE TABLE #Tab
(   Store int
    ,UpdateType char(1)
    ,ItemNumber int
    ,Name varchar(50)
)
SELECT bt.* FROM #BaseTable bt  -- Output for debugging - delete in production. 

DECLARE @count int = 1
DECLARE @Input TABLE (Store int, UpdateType char(1), ItemNumber int, Name varchar(50))
--Loop over each row to mimick how the merge will be called.
WHILE @count <= 5
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM @Input
    INSERT INTO @Input SELECT Store, UpdateType, ItemNumber, Name  FROM #BaseTable WHERE RN = @Count

    SELECT * FROM @Input    -- Output for debugging - delete in production.

    -- Procedure Body
    DECLARE @Store int, @UpdateType char(1), @ItemNumber int, @Name varchar(50)
    DECLARE csrInput CURSOR FOR SELECT Store, UpdateType, ItemNumber, Name  FROM @Input
    OPEN csrInput
    WHILE 1=1
        BEGIN
            FETCH NEXT FROM csrInput INTO @Store, @UpdateType, @ItemNumber, @Name 
            IF @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 BREAK
            IF @UpdateType = 'D'
                MERGE INTO #Tab Dest
                USING (SELECT * FROM @Input WHERE Store = @Store AND ItemNumber = @ItemNumber) Src
                ON Dest.Store = Src.Store AND Dest.ItemNumber = Src.ItemNumber
                WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Dest.UpdateType = Src.UpdateType, Dest.Name = Src.Name
                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (Store, UpdateType, ItemNumber, Name) VALUES (Src.Store, Src.UpdateType, Src.ItemNumber, Src.Name);
            ELSE    -- Assuming that @UpdateType can only be 'D' or 'R'...
                MERGE INTO #Tab Dest
                USING (SELECT * FROM @Input WHERE Store = @Store AND ItemNumber = @ItemNumber) Src
                ON Dest.Store = Src.Store AND Dest.ItemNumber = Src.ItemNumber
                WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET Dest.UpdateType = Src.UpdateType, Dest.Name = Src.Name
                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT (Store, UpdateType, ItemNumber, Name) VALUES (Src.Store, Src.UpdateType, Src.ItemNumber, Src.Name)
                WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;

                SELECT * FROM #Tab  -- Output for debugging - delete in production. 

        END
    CLOSE csrInput
    DEALLOCATE csrInput
    -- End Procedure Body.

    SET @count += 1
END
```

Final output:

```
Store UpdateType ItemNumber Name
1     D          1          Small Wheel
1     D          4          Trunk
```

Comment: The problem is, I need to delete all for the entire `Store` if `UpdateType='R'`, which is why I don't think I can use a `MERGE`, but I'm hoping I'm wrong. The data is flattened, so the `UpdateType` will be the same for each iteration/`RN`. And thanks for cleaning up the `CASE` statement.

Comment: I have a solution, however, I keep getting errors when I try to post edits or new answers.  The key is: for each record submitted to your `MERGE` procedure (use a cursor), you need to test if `UpdateType = 'D'`, and `MERGE` *without* `DELETE` if it is, and `MERGE` *with* `DELETE` if it is not.  I'll correct my answer when the problems are cleared up.

Comment: Finally overcame the stackoverflow bug.  Have a look at my answer now.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but this definitely gets the job done. I went a slightly different route but this got me on the right path and solves the question I brought up. Thanks sir!